# Load data of multiple array of a formGroup into the form ? how?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I want to load the data into the form, by clicking the edit button. Currently, I am able to load only single array data into the form. but unable to load multiple array data.

Here is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fzgtqc?Sile=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I have already patched the data into the form but only of a single array, not multiple array.

**Here is the sample data:**

```
 data = {
    "trainer_id": "t001",
    "personal_details": {
        "name": {
            "first_name": "ABC",
            "last_name": "Kumar"
        },
        "dob": "1990-12-20",
        "about_yourself": "i am a corporate trainer from 10 years",
        "languages_known": ["Kannada", "English", "Tamil"],
        "willing_to_travel": "yes"
    },
    "technologies": [{
        "name": "Angular 2",
        "experience": 4,
        "ratings": 7.9,
        "costing": {
            "freshers": 8000,
            "laterals": 12000,
            "project_specific": 15000
        },
        "work_as_consultant": "yes"
    },
  {
        "name": "Java",
        "experience": 5,
        "ratings": 8,
        "costing": {
            "freshers": 8000,
            "laterals": 12000,
            "project_specific": 15000
        },
        "work_as_consultant": "yes"
    }
  ],
    "certifications": [{
        "title": "Sun Certified",
        "Year": 1999
    }],
};
```

**Below function will be executed when an edit button is clicked**

```
editTrainner() {
    this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner = this.data;
    this.registrationForm.patchValue({
          personal_details: { type: Object,
            name: { type: Object,
                first_name: this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner.personal_details.name.first_name,
                last_name: this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner.personal_details.name.last_name
            },
            dob: this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner.personal_details.dob,
            about_yourself: this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner.personal_details.about_yourself,
            willingly_to_travel: this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner.personal_details.willingly_to_travel
        }
    });
    this.addlanguages_known();
    this.registrationForm.patchValue({
  technologies: this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner.technologies
});
  this.registrationForm.patchValue({
  certifications: this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner.certifications
});
  }
  addlanguages_known(): any {
    const control = this.registrationForm.get('personal_details.languages_known') as FormArray;
    this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner.personal_details.languages_known.forEach(x => {
        control.push(this.fb.control(x));
      });
  }
```

In the sample data, you will find **"technologies"**, in that I am to load one array group, not the second group. You can check the output in the stackblitz link.

Comment: When clicking addTech you are adding form group only, What is the issue?

Comment: @chelleppan i want to load the data into the form.

Comment: for your reference you can check the link in that their is a sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are initializing the form you only have 1 `FormGroup` in `technologies` `FormArray`. So when you are patching only 1 value gets rendered. You need to add more `FormGroup`'s to `technologies` based on server response then patch. Based on your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fzgtqc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) add this as first lines of `editTrainner` function.

```
this._trainnerservice.currentTrainner.technologies.forEach(x => {
    this.addTechnologies();
})
```

Comment: What is the use of x over here? I mean to use the x?

Comment: i understood your answer theoretically, but practically it will add the new formGroup not loading the data in it

Comment: It will add the number of `FormGroup`'s required. Then when you are patching the form with server response all the `FormGroup`'s get populated.